# Transforming dataframe to make some columns to rows in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

how can i transform this data frame

Input:

```
sex     avg_height avg_weight avg_pay
female  61         128        70000
male    69         161        89000
```

to look like this in dplyr

Expected Output:

```
            male   female
avg_height  69     61
avg_weight  161    128
avg_pay     89000  70000
```

Can I use `pivot_longer()` here?

Answer (score 1):

We may `t`ranspose and set the names from 'sex' column in `base R`

```
setNames(as.data.frame(t(df1[-1])), df1$sex)
             female  male
avg_height     61    69
avg_weight    128   161
avg_pay     70000 89000
```

---

Or may use `data.table::transpose`

```
data.table::transpose(df1, make.names = 'sex', keep.names = 'new')
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
df1 %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -sex) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = sex, values_from = value) %>% 
    column_to_rownames('name')
           female  male
avg_height     61    69
avg_weight    128   161
avg_pay     70000 89000
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(sex = c("female", "male"), avg_height = c(61L, 
69L), avg_weight = c(128L, 161L), avg_pay = c(70000L, 89000L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: I'm trying to use dplyr, would `pivot_longer()` be the correct function to use? I can't figure out the arguments though.

Comment: @Eisen updated the post